# how to access javascript variables from applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have implemented small applet on the jsp page in web app which works although I need to set PARAM tag of applet with javascript vars defined on the jsp page. Is it possible? I can see its possible the other way around: to read in javascript variables from applet. I cant find solution for reverse action.

Answer (score 2):

Have the JavaScript write the `applet` element.  Or in this day and age, use [`deployJava.js`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to write the `applet` element, and assign the JS variable to one of the parts of the `parameters`.

If `userFontSize` is the custom variable, then E.G.

```
var parameters = {
  fontSize:16, 
  jnlp_href:'java2d.jnlp'
}
```

..might become..

```
var parameters = {
  fontSize:userFontSize, 
  jnlp_href:'java2d.jnlp'
}
```